# Android custom layout design in main layout

Tags: android, android-layout, qr-code, zxing

I have to add the QRCode scan layout in my main layout than calling the new activity to load the camera to scan.

I already done that part using the ZXing library. So this I have created the layout like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/preview_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<zxing.ViewfinderView
    android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="10dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/msg_default_status"
    android:textColor="@color/status_text"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewfinder_view"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!--</merge>-->
```

Then I called the CaptureActivity from ZXing Lib, 
If It's first time load the camera to scan then it will ask the permission and show this message. Sorry, the Android camera encountered a problem. You may need to restart the device.
So 
 1. **If I closed the camera then click the open camera button then it's working.** 
 2. I need to create the custom layout for scanning like the below image screen.

Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589379/customized-camera-view-rotation-in-zxing-for-qr-code?rq=1

Comment: it will not helping to me...
My question is always load the camera like the above attached image.

Comment: @CarinaMj this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio

Comment: I also used this ZXing SDK, I am asking that, Currently I have added the button to click then open CaptureActivity, But current design when I open this Activity then the top always camera will be opened and able to scan.

Comment: Hi, How to design the camera inside my activity with the mentioned red color border. 
I have tried. but still not get the solution.

Comment: @CarinaMj hi, have you got the solution for this design?